# Move files in specific subfolders to another subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I have folder `C:\Folder`. In this folder I have thousands of subfolders. I want to target only those ending in `cv`. In these subfolders I have a file and another subfolder. `C:\Folder\SubFoldercv\cv`. I would like to move all the files in those subfolders to the second subfolder using CMD in Windows 10.

(So from `C:\Folder\SubFoldercv` to `C:\Folder\SubFoldercv\cv`).

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, Windows 10

Comment: How do you define the second subfolder? Could you please provide the actual folder tree and the script you have so far.

Comment: The second subfolder in all the subfolders are called 'cv'.
I have tried a lot of things but most of what I have tried is similar to this code: for /r "C:\\path" %%x in (*) do move "%%x" "cv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`for /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to find the directories ending with `cv`, and use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) to copy (or `robocopy /mov` to move) all files from a folder to another:

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\Folder\*cv") DO robocopy /mov "%%~G" "%%~G\cv" "*"
```

I'm currently not on a windows machine so I'm not able to test it but it should do the trick and move all files to the `cv` subfolder for all folders ending on `cv`.

If you want to use it on the command-line, use:

```
FOR /D %G IN ("*cv") DO robocopy /mov "%~G" "%~G\cv" "*"
```

instead.

**EDIT**: After the OP tested it, he has confirmed that it works.

Comment: I actually used `robocopy / move` to move the files rather than copy them, but works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear that. My apologies, I had in mind you wanted to copy. I'll edit my answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

How to do?

```
subfolderHolder = uploads

FOR /D %%i IN ("%MoveDirSource%\*\%subfolderHolder%\*") DO ROBOCOPY /MOV /E "%%i" "%MoveDirDestination%\%%~nxi"
```

but the wild card is not working

Comment: If you have a similar question, then please ask a new question. Do not post it here as an answer.